# For a cubesat mission piggybacking on a Red Dragon, what are the tradeoffs for launch early and late in the launch window?

Tags: launch, spacex, cubesat, red-dragon

SpaceX will be launching [two Red Dragons](http://www.ibtimes.co.uk/nasa-says-spacex-may-send-two-red-dragon-spacecraft-mars-2020-case-one-fails-1621053) in 2020, one at the beginning of the launch window (July) and one at the end (September).

For a CubeSat mission that would have to piggyback on one of the two Red Dragon spacecraft in order to get to Mars orbit, what are the likely pros and cons for the earlier and later launch?

Comment: What kind of orbit would the piggybacking leave the cubesat in? A nice, low planetary orbit, a high orbit, or a flyby? I'm just curious how this might be implemented.

Comment: I don't think there is any chance a cubesat piggy-backing on a Red Dragon will make orbit, I think Dragon is on a direct intercept course for Mars.

Comment: @JakeBlocker don't forget the (at)uhoh when replying! (I didn't get a notification for some reason) I'm looking for some clarification on the envisioned piggy-backing mechanism. Since Mars' atmosphere has such a low density, there will need to be substantial propulsive deceleration. Do you think they will do all of it at the end, after Dragon has entered the atmosphere? There is no opportunity for a piggy-back handler to jump off and propulsively slow a few cubesats down to orbital velocity? I wish there were something written up we could refer to!

Comment: @JakeBlocker It does take a fair amount of delta-V, but it's doable. About a month of thrust at 1 mm/s^2.

Comment: @uhoh As Jake Blocker said, the Red Dragons are on a direct intercept course (some old documents say it hits the atmosphere at 6 km/s, which fits Hohmann). More info on capture are available here: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/21618/calculating-low-thrust-capture-delta-v-with-high-v-inf

Comment: @Deimophobia OK an intercept course is what it is on *while it's on it's way there* for months, and I'm asking about what happens during the last few tens of minutes. If it is still really planned to hit the atmosphere at a Hohmann apogee velocity with no or minimal deceleration beforehand, then wow! and ok! in that order ;) I'll poke around a bit to see if that's worth asking a separate question about yet, but I hope someone else beats me to it!

Comment: @Deimophobia I think it's a little more complicated (see [this comment](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/21618/#comment60570_21637)) so I'll ask separately.

Comment: @uhoh Red Dragon? Yes, it appears to just be slamming into atmo at 6 km/s, which seems to match not doing anything until the last moment (http://www.lpi.usra.edu/meetings/marsconcepts2012/pdf/4216.pdf). The piggybacking craft ejects about a month beforehand and captures into a flat, circular orbit above Deimos (numbers in HopDavid's answer, above your linked comment).

Comment: @Deimophobia ah OK! Thanks for taking the time to explain it to me, I have a better picture of what's happening now.